# Issue with log4j2 config when used with Java modules (JPMS) & Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, log4j2, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I created a vanilla java project using gradle & then converted the project to use java modules. Without modules, the `log4j2.xml` thats present at the root of the project is picked up.

But once I converted the application to module based system, instead of picking my log4j2.xml, the framework is using its own default config.

It is my understanding that in Java Platform Module System (JPMS) [When we attempt to access a resource using `Module#getResourceAsStream`, the resources that which are not under a path that matches a package (say a root level resource in `/myfile.txt` at module root) & also when it comes to `/META-INF` folder at module root will be automatically made available to the caller module (Please correct me if I am wrong). But I am not sure about the methodology JPMS uses when deciding which modules to look up for a given resource (is it all? or does it have some other mechanism?).

In my case, I both exported & opened the module just to check if that was causing the issue. Unfortunately, that's not the reason

Any idea why this might be the case?

The source for the issue can be found at the following github repo

https://github.com/thekalinga/log4j2-config-gradle-jpms-issue

Comment: Thanks for sharing that MRE. What are the steps to observe the issue you describe? Doing *`./gradlew check`* succeeds with no program output. Doing *`./gradlew run`* results in: „*`Task 'run' not found in root project 'log4j2-vanilla'`*“. As I was reading your question (*before downloading your MRE*) I had a hunch about what might cause what you described. But not being able to reproduce what you describe makes this a non-starter. Can you edit your question (*or your github README*) to include the steps that reproduce your issue? Or refactor your MRE to produce the output you describe? TIA.

Comment: In your repo, you wrote: „*only `ERROR MSG` gets logged, not `DEBUG MSG`*“. This question intrigued me because I've used log4j 2 in several different JPMS-based Gradle projects but never seen what you describe. Your question and repo lack details on how to run your app. So I took some initiative and applied *`id 'application'`* to your *`plugins{…}`* block. Calling *`./gradlew run`* prints: „*`…DEBUG 6312 --- [main] c.e.Play : DEBUG MSG | … ERROR 6312 --- [main] c.e.Play : ERROR MSG`*“. Calling the modular jar directly with *`java … -m com.example/com.example.Play`* prints the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say with certainty because I haven't investigated it fully yet, but my guess is that, like most other libraries, Log4j 2 2.x doesn't fully support JPMS. With JPMS each module is managed by its own ClassLoader. Since Log4j is an automatic module it will be grouped with all other automatic modules but not with "true" JPMS modules. This means that when Log4 tries to locate the log4j2.xml on the "classpath" it will only find files located in other automatic modules because Log4j 2 2.x doesn't have support for locating files in other modules.

If your application is defined as a JPMS module (i.e. with a module-info.class file) then Log4j won't be able to locate a configuration file located within it.

Log4j 2 3.0 development has been underway for quite some time. The intention with it has always been to fully support JPMS so you should expect this will work when it is finally released, but getting libraries like Log4j to fully support JPMS requires quite a bit of work. As all the Log4j developers support it in their free time finding enough of it to work on everything we want can be challenging

Comment: Thanks for that. Are v3 builds accessible publicly?

Comment: You can find snapshot builds of 3.0.0 at repository.apache.org in the snapshots repository. However, you should know that support for JPMS is nowhere near done. If you would care to help patches and pull requests are always welcome!